# jQuery vs Flash?

Tags: jquery, flash

I'm pretty new to jQuery and it's limitations, I've seen a lot of cool stuff done with it but I'm wondering what the limitations are and if it is possible to recreate something like this - http://www.magnetme.co.uk/ in jQuery.

The reason I ask is we want to create some interactive elements to a new website and was thinking of going down the flash route, but obviously this alienates anyone browsing the site on iPad's and the like.

Thanks

Vince

Comment: I believe you are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Just don't limit yourself to jQuery.  Consider all that JavaScript has to offer, including various other libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work a lot with both jQuery and Flash, and see every day where jQuery or Flash comes short. Genreally jQuery is a lot easier to maintain than Flash as Flash requires recompilation before changes can be published.

There is nothing stopping you from creating a similar solution to your example (http://www.magnetme.co.uk/) in jQuery. I've done something *a little similar* on this page: http://www.tema.no/default.aspx?menu=12.

Generally I make things with jQuery when I can and Flash if there is a need for heavy/quick animations with many or big images.

This product browser is made in jQuery: http://www.devold.com/outdoor/default.aspx?menu=3. I think it's a bit too slow on some browsers. There are about 200 products.

This product browser is made in Flash: http://www.comfort.no/default.aspx?menu=668 and handles over 1000 products easily and smoothly.

Generally the pros and cons are as follows:

- **Search engine optimization:**
  It's easier to make jQuery (JavaScript) based stuff search engine optimized
- **Quickly implement changes**: Easier with jQuery than Flash as Flash must be recompiled
- **Smoothness of animations**: Flash handles animations better than jQuery
- **Multimedia**: Only Flash. Canvas and Audio/Video in HTML5 supports this, but support for HTML5 is still limited
- **Cross browser support**: When working with jQuery, you're really working with JavaScript and HTML, which has it's browser issues. For example fading in an alpha transparent PNG is a bit tricky in Internet Explorer 7. There are a few issues like this to handle. Flash on the other hand (mostly) behaves the same across browsers and platforms. Besides flash has a market penetration of ... 98% I think.
- **iPhone/iPad**: No matter what your thoughts on Apple's decision to not support Flash on their iPhones and iPads, this is an issue that you need to have an opinion about when choosing architecture.

**Update: Here are some articles that highlights HTML5 vs Flash:**

- Faux Drama by Jack (Jack is the guy behind Greensock, TweenLite, TweenMax and the other ingenuine AS tweening tools.) [http://www.greensock.com/flash-html5/](http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/roundups/html5-and-flash-17-industry-experts-have-their-say/)
- HTML5, Flash and RIAs: 18 Industry Experts Have Their Say: http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/roundups/html5-and-flash-17-industry-experts-have-their-say/

Comment: That "slow" product catalogue on devold.com could be made 100%-300% faster with some optimization.  I see things like `$(".product .content .header ul li")` which could be made faster.  Also, there are countless places where caching jQuery objects would improve speed.  Most noteably all of the references to `$(this)`.  Not that it's a bad app!  But you could overhaul it and make it much speedier.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive feedback! When I did the catalogue, I did a lot of testing to improve speed, but I found out that most of the time spent was on adding <img> tags or changing the src-attribute of the image tags. So my conclusion was that my approach of changing source attribute of the image tags was not ideal. Thanks for the feedback though. I really _want_ jQuery to perform quicker!

Comment: If you check the same site again with FireBug, you will see some traces. The code is inside http://www.devold.com/outdoor/js/jquery.cms.js, and most of the time is consumed inside line 586: $('#product-list').html(data); (which is inside checkSlider.ajax) which is the function that gets a page of products and puts it inside the html document. How would you go about to improve the speed?

Answer (score 1):

Using the HTML5 `<canvas>` element or with SVG, you can also do it with Javascript, but HTML5 isn't supported by old browsers. What you propably could get running on all browsers is generating the images on the server, but that can be very slow and bandwidth-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the example, this is something that jQuery could easily handle.

Albeit, to do this properly (read "fast loading, fast performing"), you'll need at least an intermediate to advanced understanding of jQuery fundamentals.

If you feel like your JavaScript abilities are top-notch, especially your DOM traversal techniques, I say go with jQuery.

Lastly, jQuery isn't the only kid on the block.  As @Jeff mentioned in his comment, take a look at all the frameworks on the market.  If you are more comfortable with another framework, like MooTools for example, you may be better off there.  (Personally, I'm a jQuery man.)

(Also, kill the autoloader music.  What a crock.)

Comment: Do you have any examples of jQuery doing anything similar? I would love to see an example

Comment: Here's a quick list of great plugins I found with a single google:  http://shinylittlething.com/2009/02/20/image-manipulation-jquery-plugins/

Comment: Image Resizing oin some guy's blog: http://thejudens.com/eric/2009/07/jquery-image-resize/

Comment: I could go on, but if I were to actually try the project I would spin up fresh code rather than copying something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a real man, do it all in css. Here is a sample of its raw power: [Pure CSS Fail Whale](http://www.subcide.com/experiments/fail-whale/)

Answer (score 0):

The UI would be easy enough to replicate.

To create elements that represent the cabinets and such, you're probably looking at using SVG.  You can use a JavaScript library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) to manipulate SVG elements.  SVG is supported in Mobile Safari.

I don't know how to skew images to fit non-rectangular shapes.  However, it can be done to some degree as evidenced by the [jQuery Image Cube plugin](http://keith-wood.name/imageCube.html).  Looking at the source of that plugin should lead to some ideas.

All in all, it's certainly possible to create a similar site using a JavaScript+SVG solution.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is still the king of design while jQuery is what you use to accessorize your site not build the whole thing. B Culture Media talks about this in a recent blog post at http://bculture.tumblr.com/post/15362447623/flash-is-alive.

Comment: Nice shameless self promo.  Flash is dying....want proof, check the want ads--there aren't any for Flash.  It had it's time.  The problem is that Adobe in general ignores the community, and our corporate clients are screaming for compatibility and performance, Flash's two biggest downfalls.  Then Apple got in on the Adobe bashing.  Now you're left with a dying community, improving competition, and a competitor that just thew in the towel (Silverlight is dead)  If you're hitching your horse to Adobe, be prepared to get stuck....soon!

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible in jQuery, it would take **a lot** of work, not to mention it would be rather slow. Instead you would most likely have to create a Flash solution for browsers and a HTML5 canvas solution for the iPad (which will work on most new browsers)

Comment: I disagree with this almost 100%.

Comment: This is not a Javascript solution. Have you used the app enough to see the built-in image stretching and moving? How is he going to handle all the different color wallpapers, all the different combinations of images? It would be far less work to design two solutions one for browsers and one for Apple products than trying to program this in JS and find out quickly how slow it will be.

Comment: I don't know about *your* abilities, but speak for yourself.  There are plenty of examples on the web of image stretching and moving with JavaScript.  And handling different wallpapers is trivial.  I stand by the fact that this would be easily accomplished in a matter of days with an experienced programmer.